# Why would a PayPal settlement report not include a T0401 entry even though AutoSweep is on and has run?

Tags: paypal

We asked to have AutoSweep activated for our PayPal merchant account.

Funds were automatically transferred to our bank as expected, but PayPal's settlement reports did not list it as code T0401, which [the docs](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/PP_LRD_Gen_SettlementReport.pdf) suggested should happen.

Instead the reports listed it as T0400 which is for "Settlement Withdrawal or user-initiated".

Any ideas?

Comment: Curious why this was downvoted. I posted this as a self-answered question in the hopes that it would help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that autosweep and settlement withdrawal are two entirely separate PayPal products (I helped write them).

Autosweep is a simple product that just transfers your end-of-day balance out to your bank.

Settlement Withdrawal is a more complex product that sums your daily activity and transfers out the day's net revenue, along with providing accompanying reports of the activity that generated the transfer.

And yeah, it's not surprising that you could ask for one and get the other. PayPal has built a LOT of products over the years and few people @ PayPal are well versed in all of them. OK, let me be honest: I doubt there is a person on the planet who knows ALL of them :-).

Comment: Excellent to get this confirmed. Both the technical part and that no one at PayPal quite knows what's going on ;) Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

We contacted PayPal support. They stated that "T0401 is an old code that should no longer be used, especially in Europe", and that it was intentional that we got T0400 instead.

My theory (not verified with PayPal yet) is that [AutoSweep and Settlement Withdrawal are two different but similar things](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-services-Archive/Auto-Sweep-vs-Settlement-Withdrawl/td-p/365674), and our account got Settlement Withdrawal activated even though we asked for AutoSweep (perhaps because we're in Europe?). And Settlement Withdrawal *is* documented to use T0400.